# Trouble updating Modules in Drupal 7 with FTP

Tags: 7

I'm developing in localhost. When I try to update modules, it requires FTP access. I've tried several ways by installing `vsftpd` and adding my user account to `ftp` group, chowing the files, etc. But, I'm ending up with following message:

*File Transfer failed, reason: Unable to remove to file /media/location-of-drupal/module/blahblah*

Now, I've decided not to use FTP. **Can I just manually download latest copies and unzip > paste the modules?** Will that work? And is it applicable to updating Drupal core?

Thanks :)

**EDIT:** I've managed to fix FTP, and is now updating modules by FTP. But still, I'd like to know the answer, i.e. does copy-paste works perfectly? I posted my answer here: http://bdhacker.wordpress.com/2011/11/26/update-drupal-modules-using-ftp-in-localhost/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it works. What I figured out is - one needs to:

1. Download any module's updated release, extract and override older version of the module.
2. Run ***update.php*** found in the directory of Drupal's root - very important to update your database.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same effect.

The instructions at http://bdhacker.wordpress.com/2011/11/26/update-drupal-modules-using-ftp-in-localhost/ have all the necessary details. Especially the vsftp config (/etc/vsftpd.conf) is important. Make sure the following options are set:

listen=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022

Don't forget to restart vsftpd after config changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could... you could also bring them home on a floppy disk. ;)

Seriously though - get yourself [git](http://git-scm.com/). [Install it](http://book.git-scm.com/2_installing_git.html) on your local machine, create repository (or use a service like [GitHub](http://github.com/), [XP-Dev](http://xp-dev.com/) or whatever else if your machine is not accessible from the internet), and start using proper version control! A bit of hassle at the beginning with setting everything up, but then makes your life tremendously easier...

Comment: Hmm... you're suggesting I clone more than 20+ modules? Well, pretty good. But does just replacing the source code is OK? I mean, do I need to "update database" or something like that?

Comment: No, what I'm suggesting is to clone the WHOLE site. That's the point of using version control tools. In your specific case though, I don't know, it all depends on changes between the version your have right now and the one you are going to replace it with. <code>Status report</code> will tell you if the update is required or not...

Answer (score 0):

After all you just have to make sure all your files are transfered in a consistent Way feom your local dev to production.

If you have shell access on production git is an excelent way of doing this. A lot of people are worling rhis way. We have been using rsync succesfully for a long time. FTP is just a remote file transfer tool you have to do at least some manual book keeping that the other tools doing for you once you set them up properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it simple, Just follow the steps below:

1. Download the module from Drupal
2. Extract or Unzip it
3. Place it in /sites/all/modules/ directory
4. Enable the module from admin end